# C# Rotate 2 controls around a center point at the defaul angle in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, rotation, controls, point

I was trying to rotate 2 windows form button as in the following image:

[image: example image]

During their rotation, the distance between them should be 0 and when you click a label, they should "rotate" 90 degree, as like:

```
if (red is up and black is down)
{
    red will be down and black will be up;
}
else 
{
    red will be up and black will be down;
}
```

I used this method to return the desired point "location", but i couldn't obtain the desired rotation "effect":

```
 public static Point Rotate(Point point, Point pivot, double angleDegree)
    {
        double angle = angleDegree * Math.PI / 180;
        double cos = Math.Cos(angle);
        double sin = Math.Sin(angle);
        int dx = point.X - pivot.X;
        int dy = point.Y - pivot.Y;
        double x = cos * dx - sin * dy + pivot.X;
        double y = sin * dx + cos * dy + pivot.X;

        Point rotated = new Point((int)Math.Round(x), (int)Math.Round(y));
        return rotated;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the rotation point will be set in a timer for the rotation effect to took place.

Comment: you need a timer which sets a RAD offset for the parametric equation for a circle

Comment: I don't know very much trugonometry, an example would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like in my comment it has to look like this:

```
private Point calculateCircumferencePoint(double radoffset, Point center, double radius)
        {
            Point res = new Point();

            double x = center.X + radius * Math.Cos(radoffset);
            double y = center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(radoffset);

            res.X = (int)x;
            res.Y = (int)y;

            return res;
        }
```

here is also a test application: https://github.com/hrkrx/TestAppCircularRotation

EDIT: for a second button you just need to set the initial offset to `Math.PI`;

EDIT2: To rotate the buttons like they cross (like the path of an 8) you need to set the radius to `Sin(radoffset)` or `Cos(radoffset)`

Comment: And for the the buttons to be with no distance between them, rotating them like swutching their place, i need to decreese the offse or the radius?

Comment: its depending on what you want to achieve, but i assume you are right.

Comment: to automate the distance you could set the radius to `(radoffset % Math.PI) * constvalue`

Comment: If i set the radius like that in the timer before calculating the circumference, the button will slow down and jump from a location to another.

Comment: you have to experiment a bit with the values to get the perfect result ;)

Comment: One more question, can your code so the button to rotate around themselves too? I mean how the earth is rotating: around the sun and also around its x y axis.

Comment: sure just use `button1.Location` as center for `button2`

Comment: to rotate the button itself, you need to use WPF because in forms there is no rotation property

Comment: Yes but if the button2 will move in the other direction, how can button1 still rotating around it? It doesn't even have to. they both need to rotate clock wise.

Comment: i increment the radoffset, so to inverse the rotation you need to decrement it ;) to adjust the speed you need to modify the stepsize or the timerinterval ;)

Comment: Basically this is my code rewritten a bit of how i tried to make the movement: http://s18.postimg.org/6g1go5qrt/Untitled.png And i also found this game which is very similar of what i want to do. The rotation of those candies. Check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pldfEX3qxpI

Comment: the code i used for the rotation is the basic minimum and you can even flip the buttons like the candys with it ;) you just have to keep in mind that if the radoffset reaches 1/2PI or 3/2PI its on the highest/lowest point of the circle ;) And the candys have the same rotationcenter